# What is the difference among following sentences?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Somebody please explain differences among these sentences to me:

> I'm feeling like I'm famous
>
> I'm feeling like a famous person
>
> I feel like a famous person

And meaning of this sentence too:

> It feels like I'm doing well

Comment: There is little difference between "I am famous" and "I am a famous person," as it implied that the speaker is a person.

Comment: LOL!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Kys meant to write _"...it **is** implied..."_